# Rest API - Fields and Expand Query Parameters Best Practices/Approach

Tags: java, spring, rest, api

I'm starting in the Rest APIs world, and would like everyone's help to understand the difference in using ***?fields=*** and ***?expand=*** in my URI.

Searching the Web I found a good explanation in this article: [In Here](https://developers.digitalriver.com/rest-apis/basic-concepts/understanding-fields-and-expand-query-parameters)

Is this the right way/best approach to using these? Or for the present day this is no longer a good practice? For example the ***Projection*** in the query parameter indicating how will be the representations of each relationships.

E.G.: `GET /Events/1?venueProjection=full,teamProjection=uri`

I'm using **Spring Boot** with **Rest** and **Data**, is there anything ready inside this ecosystem that helps me work this way? I found this Open Ticket of 2014 that already entered this merit ([Spring Jira Ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-243))

Thanks in advance for your help and understanding.

Comment: Is this still a question? Just came across it.

Comment: @MohammadNajar yes, please share with me :)